# Conforming New Edge Loops On a Curved Mesh to the Curve

Tags: modeling

Let's say I have a curved mesh and I add a loop cut:

[image: curved mesh with loop cut]

The new loop cut does not touch the curve as the others do.

My question is, is there a tool/addon for achieving the following result in a more precise manner than just translating the loop cut by eye:

[image: desired outcome]

This is a simple example, but I'm hoping to apply it to more complicated meshes.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using *To Sphere* operator with `Shift`+`Alt`+`S` (with one edge loop selected). The geometry should be converted into the circle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the curve object. Key <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to open the *Convert to* menu and choose *Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text* or key *2*. Key <kbd>T</kbd> to toggle open/close the *Toolshelf*. Check *Keep Original* in the *Convert to* dropdown. This adds a new mesh object, rather than converting the curve. This is useful because if you decide to change the curve later, you still can, without having to convert back to a curve, edit, and return to a mesh.

[image]

Select the object that you were loop cutting. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*. Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to add a loopcut, position it where you like, <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> to confirm, and immediately <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>.
Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[comma]</kbd> to change to *Pivot point > Median point*. Choose *Transform Orientation > Normal*. Enable *Snapping* and change the settings to *Edge > Closest*. Your *3D Viewport's* bottom bar should now have these settings:

[image]

Drag on the green arrow until the loop cut snaps.

[image]